# Check if Kubuntu is running on 64bit or 32bit machine

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, kubuntu

How can I check if my kubuntu is running in a 64 bits or 32 machine using terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
uname -a
```

My machine gives this:

```
Linux james-desktop 2.6.38-11-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 19:02:55 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It should be easy to figure out if your box is 32 bit or 64 bit from the string your box gives you.

Comment: To clarify this: a line with `_64` would indicate a 64-bit install, whereas a line with `i686` would indicate a 32-bit install.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-to-find-if-processor-is-64-bit-or-not/) says to run

```
$ grep flags /proc/cpuinfo
```

and if the `lm` flag (long mode, I think) is present, you have a 64-bit CPU. The same page also describes [JamWaffles](https://superuser.com/questions/333706/check-if-kubuntu-is-running-on-64bit-or-32bit-machine/333707#333707)'s answer of using the kernel's targeted architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You can check what is your kubuntu architecture (a 64 bits or 32 machine) using terminal run

`getconf WORD_BIT`

It will show 32 or 64-bit kUbuntu.

Comment: By far the most useful - the CPU is 64 bit, it's got a "lm" flag, but it's WORD_BIT is set to 32, which explains a few things.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

look for "lm" under flags LM stands for [Long Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode) - which is support for a 64 bit programme to access 64 bit instructions