# Check if my machine is 64-bit capable on Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit, architecture

Similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/251014/how-to-check-whether-my-hardware-is-64-bit-capable-in-windows) question, I have a 32-bit OS (Ubuntu), but I want to know if my machine is 64-bit capable... I checked out the question, but the answers are Windows-specific... I also checked [this](https://superuser.com/questions/333706/check-if-kubuntu-is-running-on-64bit-or-32bit-machine) question, but I want to know if it is 64-bit capable, I know my OS is 32-bit.

Thanks, whoever I am

Comment: usually the best bet is to look up your CPU model online. you can use lshw to tell you.

Comment: Please include the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` in your question.

Comment: `lscpu` should work as well . . .

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate question and has been asked many times. `grep ' lm ' /proc/cpuinfo` - no output = 32 bit processor.  lm = long mode == 64 bit capable and is considered the most relilable flag.

Comment: [How can I check if my CPU is AMD64 compatible?](http://askubuntu.com/q/133111/74792) from Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Just a note note of caution: even if your CPU is capable of running a 64-bit OS, it is not always advisable to do so. The Ubuntu site recommends 32-bit Ubuntu if you have less than 2GB of RAM. 64-bit code is always bigger, and any gain in CPU speed is swamped by the degradation if there is increased swapping activity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

run (as root/sudo)

```
lshw -class CPU
```

and look at the `Width` attribute. If its `64bit`, your hardware is capable.

More info here: http://www.basiclinuxcommand.com/lshw/check-cpu-processor-type-information-linux-fedora-using-lshw-command.html

Comment: This should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw a revision of Frank Thomas's answer into the ring.  Enter this into your terminal and the answer will be pretty obvious.

```
lshw -class CPU | grep -i "width"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Intel processor, they provide their own site with tons of information of each processor, called the [Intel ARK.](http://ark.intel.com/) Just search for your processor there, and it will have a section called `Intel 64`, with either a yes or no box.

For AMD processors, here is a [list of all their processors](http://products.amd.com/pages/desktopcpuresult.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), and by pressing `View Details` you can see if it is 64-bit capable.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do it is by googling the cpu. You can pull the CPU from the BIOS and a look for the specs from Intel, Newegg, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways of knowing this is, using the `lscpu` command

```
lscpu
```

Output

```
mir@Dell:~$ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   45 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          2
On-line CPU(s) list:             0,1
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           78
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz
Stepping:                        3
CPU MHz:                         1992.004
BogoMIPS:                        3984.00
Hypervisor vendor:               VMware
Virtualization type:             full
L1d cache:                       64 KiB
L1i cache:                       64 KiB
L2 cache:                        512 KiB
L3 cache:                        3 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0,1
```

**Architecture: x86_64**  -> This means you are currently running a **64-bit** OS

**CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit**  -> This means your CPU is capable of running both **32-bit and 64-bit** OS

> Identify 32-bit or 64-bit

```
Architecture: X86, i686, i386  -> 32-bit OS

Architecture: X64, amd64, X86_64  -> 64-bit OS
```