# win10 32bit on x86-64

Tags: windows-10, x86

I currently have an laptop running Linux, and I'm considering dual-booting to Windows 10. I try to decide whether to take 32bit or 64bit OS.

If I understood correctly, 64bit Windows might be better than 32bit for heavy RAM usage, but worse for light usage. is that correct?

I do have a 8GB memory card (so 32bit can't map it all), but I don't intend to use much memory on the Windows, does it still make the 64bit faster?

Last but not least (least trivial maybe), I read that with the shift to 64bit processors, Intel introduces 2 additional changes to their x86 processors:

1. adding general-purpose registers
2. altering the stack-based calling convention, so that less "store" and "load" instruction are executed.

Theoretically, a 32bit OS may check if it's running on a 64bit processor in order to benefit from those changes, right? Does Windows 10 (32bit) do that? can it be done for 32bit programs on a 64bit Windows?

Comment: Don't even think about installing the 32-bit version!

Comment: If your processor is x64 then go with 64 bit. 32 bit is light but in performance 64 bit is always better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

32-bit OS will not check if it's running on a 64-bit processor and cannot benefit from any of the 64-bit architecture features. Neither do/can 32-bit applications.

There is no reason whatsoever to install a 32-bit version for your system.
64-bit OS has some other-than-max-accessible-RAM advantages, including Kernel Patch Protection, support for hardware-backed Data Execution Protection (DEP) and way higher limitations for things like user mode process max size, paged and non-paged pool max size, page table entries and system cache.

Answer (score 0):

If your processor supports 64-bit, then 64-bit Windows10 is highly recommended, as this will enable most of the advanced featuers available for 64bit users. 

Here's how you can check if your processor supports 64-bit: [Check if my machine is 64-bit capable on Linux (Ubuntu)?](https://superuser.com/questions/770554/check-if-my-machine-is-64-bit-capable-on-linux-ubuntu)